# CloseHandle((Handle) port) is not returning

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

I am having an issue with windows closeHandle((Handle)port) function in our .dll. it is not returning. The issue happens every few hours.

The java application using the .dll connects,  reads and writes data. The last method call java application does is to write the data and release method is called IMMEDIATELY which calls closeHandle function in the JNI.

Is CloseHandle not returning because write is still happening? Is there a way to gracefully return to normal when the closeHandle hangs/ not return. Thanks in advance.

The code for the function which calls closeHandle is attached.

```
{
    HANDLE port;
    jfieldID portFID = GetFieldId(env, jthis, "portnbr", "J");
    if ( portFID == 0 ){
        flog("ERROR: Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_close() portFID=0\n");
        return;
    }
    port = (HANDLE)env->GetLongField(jthis, portFID);
    if ( 0 != port ) {
        flog("Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_close() port %d\n", port);
        int count = 0;
        while ( !CloseHandle((HANDLE)port) && count < 10 ) {
            flog("ERROR Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_close() closeHandle failed with an error %d\n", count, port, GetLastError);
            flog("ERROR Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_close() failed count %d port %d\n", count, port);
            count++;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        env->SetLongField(jthis, portFID, (jlong)0);
    }
    CloseLog();
} `

The code to open a port is below

`JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_open(JNIEnv *env, jobject jthis, jstring jportName, jint baud, jbyte dataBits, jchar parity, jbyte stop, jchar flowin, jchar flowout, jchar rts, jchar cts, jchar dtr, jchar dsr, jint usTimeout)
{
    int result;
    jboolean iscopy;
    HANDLE port;

   StartLog();
    const char *portName = env->GetStringUTFChars(jportName, &iscopy);
    flog("serial port open %s baud %d data %d parity %c stop %d\n", portName, baud, dataBits, parity, stop);


// ================ DEBUG ======================================================
    /*
    {
        jclass thisClass;
        if (! (thisClass = env->GetObjectClass(jthis))) {
            flog("GetFieldId thisClass=NULL\n");
            return (0);
        }
        jmethodID getComPort = env->JNIEnv_::GetMethodID(thisClass, "getComPort", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        jfieldID  tempFID = GetFieldId(env, jthis, "comPort", "Ljava/lang/String;");
        flog("   getComPort=%d\n",getComPort);
        flog("   comPort=%d\n",tempFID);
    }
    */
// ================ DEBUG ======================================================

    jfieldID portFID = GetFieldId(env, jthis, "portnbr", "J");
    flog("   portFID=%d\n",portFID);
    if (portFID == 0) {
        flog("ERROR: Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_open() portFID=0\n");
        return (jint)-1;
    }
    port = (HANDLE)env->GetLongField(jthis, portFID);
    if (0 != port) {
        flog("ERROR: Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_open() port %d\n", port);
        CloseHandle((HANDLE)port);
    }
    port = (HANDLE)serOpen((char *)portName, baud, dataBits, parity, stop, flowin, flowout, rts, cts, dtr, dsr, usTimeout);
    if (port != NULL) {
        result = (jint)1;
    } else {
        errCode = GetLastError();
        flog("Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_open() port %d, errorcode=%d\n", port, errCode);
        result = (jint)-1;
    }
    flog("Java_com_hctsi_comm_Serial_open() port %d\n", port);
    env->SetLongField(jthis, portFID, (jlong)port);
    return(jint)result;
} `
```

Comment: You do know about the [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and `SocketServer` classes in Java, right? Why do you require JNI?

Comment: I am working with serial ports.

Comment: A port number is not a handle. And why the retry loop? Either it works or it doesn't. Doing it ten times won't change that. Very strange code. And you need `GetLastError()`, not `GetLastError`, and you need to tell us what the error code was, and supply the Java code and the code that opened the port.

Comment: retry logic is legacy. I am a little intimidated to touch it. About the GetLastError(), Point taken. There was no error because the first call to closeHandle never returns and execution doesn't continue.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the CloseHandle() function, internally windows translates that to IRP_MJ_CLOSE device control code and calls the device driver with the control code. After that it is up to the device driver to close all the operation and return the status code back to the caller.

A badly written serial port driver (that is possibly waiting for lock to be released, or waiting on operation to complete, or doing things that it is not supposed to do) will block the call and prevent it from returning to the caller. Is is quite possible that a write operation, as you speculated, is still happening and the driver is just waiting for the operation to complete. What should really be happening is that the serial port driver should abort all the operation and close and return the call immediately. But who knows how the driver has been written.

If you are inclined to find out, you can attach a kernel debugger to your serial port driver and intercept the IRP_MJ_CLOSE and that will give you your answer.

Another thing I noticed in your code is that you are trying to close the port if the CloseHandle() returned error. This is not the right way to handle it. Since it failed to close the handle the first time, why do you expect the close to succeeded in next call? Unless it is well documented by the driver writer that if CloseHandle() failed, you should call it again upto 10 times, I would immediately log the failure of close and return.

Comment: The last "write" method has returned immediately and successfully. I guess it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: You can call try calling FlushFileBuffers() function after write and before CloseHandle() and see if that fixes the issue. Generally issues like this requires that you have to work with the hardware vendor who wrote the device driver and have them fix the bug.

Comment: we are going to try closehandle from a new thread and wait for it to return for one sec. if it doesn't try two more times in two different threads. Do you think will that help any? Thank you

Comment: Did the FlushFileBuffers() not fix the issue? You can try passing the handle to different thread to close it and let the thread run for 30 sec or so. No need to try it again if it doesn't work the first time. Either way you will end up with resource leak if the CloseHandle() call does not return immediately. If your program is really long running, you will notice your resource consumption grow over time. Right way is to get the bug fixed in the driver.